# File xxxxx.package doesn't exists when run WorkItem

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to run a WorkItem in a activity. My command looks like this:

```
"$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[rvtFile].path) /al $(appbundles[GetSheetsApp].path)"
```

When I try to run the workitem I'm getting this error:

```
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] End download phase successfully.
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Command line: []
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Identified standalone application at T:\Aces\AcesRoot\22.0\coreEngine\Exe\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i T:\Aces\Jobs\6a1c0738cc0944ba9f533894d7d2ed60\c2187d8d-e6fc-429f-8aa1-d1191c8476ce.rvt /al T:\Aces\Applications\5406ab49eb5d5e06b7e519d3d8a9f7a1.H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheetsApp[1].package.
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Error: File '5406ab49eb5d5e06b7e519d3d8a9f7a1.H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheetsApp[1].package' doesn't exist.
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Error: An unexpected error was encountered during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[06/20/2023 13:37:17] Job Status:
```

Specifically this row:

```
"Error: File '5406ab49eb5d5e06b7e519d3d8a9f7a1.H2T2ElrwMLlyouCRWb09bXHWJanAz0fW.GetSheetsApp[1].package' doesn't exist."
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved it. The error was the command line. I was using the VS Code extension to create the WorkItem, and in this case should look like this:

```
$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i "$(args[rvtFile].path)" /al "$(appbundles[GetSheetsApp].path)"
```

Putting quotes in the variables, and removing them from the beginning and the end.